Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. ... swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0)
I am using Spring MVC 5.3.23 (Not Spring Boot) + SpringDoc 1.8
If I access http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
It is redirected to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
And shows below

I am following the Zagrebin's commend on How to Integrate Open API 3 with Spring project (not Spring Boot) using springdoc-openapi
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.springdoc"})
@Import({org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.class,
         org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration.class,
         org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties.class,
         org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties.class,
         org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})
public class OpenApiConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().openapi("3.0.0")
                .info(new Info()
                    .title("iBench API")
                    .version("1.0.0");
    }

}


I have searched all over and spending a week but no clue so far and tried many things but no luck yet.
Anyone has any idea to solve it?
Edit:
Some say I need to set
swagger: "2.0" 
or
openapi: "3.0.0"
But there is no yaml file for SpringDoc in the current project.
So, I have no idea how to set swagger or openapi version.
==> It runed out .openapi("3.0.0") in the OpenApiConfig is enough.
Edit:
Ah, I found /v3/api-docs returns
"{"openapi":"3.0.0","info":{"title":"iBench API","description":"ABC"}}"
This is incorrect and the correct form should be
{"openapi":"3.0.0",…}
someone suggested to add StringHttpMessageConverter but it is already there as one of default converters. I haven't modify/delete them so I guess I already have StringHttpMessageConverter???

Edit: After changing the dependencies as below, the escaping issue is gone
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
   </dependency>

but now the result of /v3/api-docs returns BASE64 encoded string looks like
"eyJvcGVuYXBpIjoiMy4wLjAiLCJpbmZvI…"
Edit: apparently it is "re-serialization" issue.
It is similar to the issue mentioned on another post below
Strings sent through Web API's gets wrapped in quotes
The thing is that I have no issue with custom controllers which are returning results in JSON format correctly but only the result from /v3/api-docs is being re-serialized.
So, still no solution found.

Ah.... there was a custom converter inside one of the Spring conf XML files.
That is why it was disturbing the result.
There are so many XML files so I missed it.
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter should be the first converter but the custom converter inside the XML file has priority.
So it could be fixed by putting ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter before the custom converter as shown below .
<mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
    <bean class="abc.CustomMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
</mvc:message-converters>

